# How do I know what the max volts and amps for this motor

Tags: voltage, power, amperage, torque

Got it from the brush roller in a shark vacuum

[image]
[image: whats the best way to mount it]
[image]

Comment: There's absolutely no way of knowing without the model number, manufacturer, etc. of the motor.

Comment: Here you go find the parameters yourself: https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_I_can_determine_the_parameters_of_a_brushed_DC_motor_experimentally_using_speed_vs_input_voltage

Comment: "Shark vacuum." Is that a vacuum cleaner that sucks up whole sharks?  Or is it a vacuum to clean your sharks?  Or just a vacuum cleaner model named shark?

Comment: It's lowercase so it's not a brand name. It must be for sucking or cleaning sharks. Capitals matter.

Comment: the dolphin vacuum has intelligent motors

Answer (score 2):

1. You determine if the machine is battery operated or plugged into a wall receptacle.
2. Trace the wiring to see if the motor is operated directly from the source voltage or if some electronic control device reduces the voltage.
3. If it is operated directly from a battery or wall receptacle voltage, determine what that voltage is by looking at the markings on the machine or examining the batteries or battery requirement markings. If you can identify a power supply module look at the markings on that.
4. If the power comes from a circuit that is not marked, turn the machine on and measure the voltage at the source.
5. If the power comes from a wall receptacle, you can assume that the maximum current for the motor is the maximum current marked on the machine minus the current required by what ever else in the machine is powered through the same plug.
6. The minimum current is whatever you measure when you connect the motor to the proper voltage with no load applied to the shaft.
7. You can see if you can find a replacement motor for the machine and find out if the seller has detailed information.
8. You can put the motor back in the machine, operate the machine and measure how much current the motor draws.